# how use JSON file using javascript on a function twice

Tags: javascript, html, json, scope, global-variables

I'm trying to create a webpage where I can it loads, it create a data from the .js file and populate into a drop-down list.

when the user select a data, it will bring the output into the output field. 
how can i possibly do that? please help

Js file is here "http://www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.js"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="id01" onchange="getURL()"></select >
<p id="output"></p>
<script>
function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<option>' + arr[i].url + '</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}

function getURL(){

myFunction();
//the display and url should be placed on output field <p>

}
</script>

<script src="myTutorials.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the code and the comments and let me know if something is not clear.

```js
// from the file
var arr = [
  {
    "display": "HTML Tutorial",
    "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"
  },
  {
    "display": "CSS Tutorial",
    "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"
  },
  {
    "display": "JavaScript Tutorial",
    "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"
  },
  {
    "display": "jQuery Tutorial",
    "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp"
  },
  {
    "display": "JSON Tutorial",
    "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp"
  },
  {
    "display": "AJAX Tutorial",
    "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp"
  },
  {
    "display": "SQL Tutorial",
    "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp"
  },
  {
    "display": "PHP Tutorial",
    "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp"
  },
  {
    "display": "XML Tutorial",
    "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp"
  }
];

function myFunction(arr) {
  var out = "";
  var i;
  out += '<option>Pick a website</option>';
  for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    /* set the value as the URL, and the text as the display property to thow clean text for the user
    and functionality text to the browser.*/
    out += '<option value="' + arr[i].url + '">' + arr[i].display + '</option>';
  }
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}

// when user pick an option (onchange), show the select's value in the #output
function getURL(select)  {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = select.value;
}

// call the fill function on body ready
myFunction(arr);
```

```html
<select id="id01" onchange="getURL(this)"></select>
<p id="output"></p>
```

**Update**

In the below example we use the *http://www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.js* script to populate the data

**Note** You must understand that it's a very specific scenario. In the real world you will not get files like this (which call to specific function). In the most of the cases you will need to use `ajax` to get data from external resources and this is totally different thing. [To read more about ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) and [ajax with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```html
<script>
  function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    out += '<option>Pick a website</option>';
    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      /* set the value as the URL, and the text as the display property to thow clean text for the user
    and functionality text to the browser.*/
      out += '<option value="' + arr[i].url + '">' + arr[i].display + '</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
  }

  // when user pick an option (onchange), show the select's value in the #output
  function getURL(select)  {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = select.value;
  }
</script>

<select id="id01" onchange="getURL(this)"></select>
<p id="output"></p>

<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if the file is external? how can I parse or declare it on an HTML

Comment: the snippet wont run. in my case, i don't have a server to run on this file. i only need to run this on my local network. I read some tutorials about ajax but i think i does not support on local network. but if i'm wrong. please tell me how. your first snippet is correct but i need the js or json file to access externally so i could update the js file every now and then. thank you very for your help and I look  forward on getting this right. :)

Comment: but what if i have two values each display like URL and overview. how can possibly do that?

Comment: can i do that using json or i need to access using ajax and jQuery?

Comment: You can do this but with native `select` it will looks ugly (A lot of text) so you can use a plugin like http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo.